# Why equals always return false in layout xml (databinding)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I'm working on this project https://developer.android.google.cn/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-project-lunch-tray , and the final project is very similar to https://github.com/ErickPimentel/LunchTray , but I add `android:checked` to `RadioButton`, for example, `@{viewModel.accompaniment.name.equals(@string/bread)}` (I put all hard coded strings in `string.xml`).
But it does not work fine, it can't checked any radio button.

Comment: make sure both strings getting  compared are in same  case, like either upper or lower. or you can use equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: @ashutosh-ojha yes, I'm sure. and the @string/*** work well on android:text and android:onClick, it can get correct result.

Comment: Have you  tried this check case in programmatically  ? Can you share your viewModel where you are  setting the  value  to "name" ?

Comment: No, I haven't. The code https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzuncty46wfx466/lunch-tray.zip?dl=0. @ashutosh-ojha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check your AccompanimentMenuFragment                     android:checked="@{viewModel.accompaniment.name.equals(@string/pickles)}"

Here viewModel.accompaniment.name has value "Pickled Veggies" and in string "pickles".

viewModel.setAccompaniment(@string/pickles)}" is setting value from your DataSource which has name "Pickled Veggies".

_accompaniment.value = menuItems[accompaniment] in  this  line menuItems[accompaniment] is getting value from DataSource which  has

"pickles" to
MenuItem(
name = "Pickled Veggies",
description = "Pickled cucumbers and carrots, made in house",
price = 0.50,
type = ItemType.ACCOMPANIMENT
)

Hence  you  "Pickled Veggies" is getting  compared with "pickles" which  gives false result.
Same issue is  with other fragments